# Fetching results from a mysql query in ZF2

Tags: mysql, frameworks, zend-framework2

Here is my model:

```
<?php

namespace Object\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;

class SiteVisitsTable {

protected $tableGateway;
protected $sql;

public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway) {
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    $this->sql = new Sql($this->tableGateway->adapter);
}

public function getVisits($field = '', $value = '') {
    if ($field = '' || $value = ''):
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array($field => $value));
    else:
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select();
    endif;

    $row = $rowset->current();
    return $row;
}

public function getAllVisits() {
    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->adapter;

    $select = $this->sql->select();
    $select->from($this->tableGateway->getTable());
    $select->columns(array(
        new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('SUM(`unique`) as `unique`'),
        new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('SUM(`impressions`) as `impressions`'),
    ));

    $selectString = $this->sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
    $resultSet = $adapter->query($selectString, $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

    return $resultSet;
}

public function addVisit($date) {
    $currentVisits = $this->getVisits('date', $date);
    if ($currentVisits) {
        $data = array(
            'unique' => $currentVisits + 1,
        );

        $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('date' => $date));
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'unique' => 1,
            'impressions' => 1,
        );

        $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
    }
}
}
```

In the getAllVisits public method I have a SELECT CUM MySQL query. Everything's okay with the query itself but I can't print the values from the query. Here is the dump of $resultSet:

```
Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet Object
(
[allowedReturnTypes:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => arrayobject
        [1] => array
    )

[arrayObjectPrototype:protected] => ArrayObject Object
    (
        [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[returnType:protected] => arrayobject
[buffer:protected] => 
[count:protected] => 1
[dataSource:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result Object
    (
        [statementMode:protected] => forward
        [resource:protected] => PDOStatement Object
            (
                [queryString] => SELECT SUM(`unique`) as `unique`, SUM(`impressions`) as `impressions` FROM `site_visits`
            )

        [options:protected] => 
        [currentComplete:protected] => 
        [currentData:protected] => 
        [position:protected] => -1
        [generatedValue:protected] => 0
        [rowCount:protected] => 1
    )

[fieldCount:protected] => 2
[position:protected] => 
)
```

You may see the queryString key and when I execute the "raw" query in phpmyadmin, it displays the values from the MySQL database, but when trying to display them in ZF2, it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my controller:

```
    return new ViewModel(array(
                'todayVisits' => $this->getSiteVisitsTable()->getVisits('date', date('Y-m-d')),
                'allVisits' => $this->getSiteVisitsTable()->getAllVisits(),
                'yesterdayVisits' => $this->getSiteVisitsTable()->getVisits('date', ''),
                'inactiveBlogs' => $this->getBlogsTable()->getInactiveBlogs(),
                'inactiveUsers' => $this->getUsersTable()->getUsers('is_active', '0'),
                'notes' => $this->getAdminNotesTable()->getAllNotes(),
                'form' => $form,
            ));
```

And my view:

```
<article class="stats_overview">
<div class="overview_today">
    <p class="overview_day">Днес</p>
    <p class="overview_count"><?php echo $todayVisits->unique; ?></p>
    <p class="overview_type">посещения</p>
    <p class="overview_count"><?php echo $todayVisits->impressions; ?></p>
    <p class="overview_type">импресии</p>
</div>
<div class="overview_previous">
    <p class="overview_day">Общо</p>
    <p class="overview_count"><?php echo $allVisits->unique; ?></p>
    <p class="overview_type">посещения</p>
    <p class="overview_count"><?php echo $allVisits->impressions; ?></p>
    <p class="overview_type">импресии</p>
</div>
</article>
```

P.S. I have the same problem with the JOIN queries! :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors do you get trying to access the queried values?

Comment: Not sure if you get an issue using `unique` reserved word as a column name..

Comment: I don't get nothing. They just do not exist. I get no error. The query is okay, because I use apostrophes (yes, unique is a reserved word). When I execute the query from the queryString (see the dump) in phpmyadmin, I get the wanted result, but when in ZF2, i do not get anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can see my Model:

```
<?php

namespace Home\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;


class VisitTable extends AbstractTableGateway {

    protected $table = 'counter';


    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter) {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
        $this->resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Visit());

        $this->initialize();
    }



    public function sumVisit(Select $select = null) {
        if (null === $select)
            $select = new Select();
        $select->from($this->table)->columns(array(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('SUM(`luongtruycap`) as `luongtruycap`')));
        $resultSet = $this->selectWith($select);
        $row = $resultSet->current();
        return $row;
    }


}
```

And Controller:

```
$visit = $this->getVisitTable()->sumVisit();
return new ViewModel(array(
                'allVisits' => $visit->luongtruycap,

            ));
```

View:

```
<p class="overview_count"><?php echo $this->allVisits; ?></p>
```

Best regards,

Ngô Tôn

Comment: Could you post any comments on how the code works? (whether in the code as comments, or outside as paragraphs)